# pattern not printing while trying to match same string on two files

Tags: perl, loops

I am trying to find pattern from two different files and  then need to sum the last values of two filesand then print sum with first ,second and third field(sum) in xls...this is so far i wrote but it is printing value of first if loop not sure why not printing for second.if somone having better logic than below to do same operation ...

```
file1.txt 
L01B,"ABC",832048921.62
L01E,"DDD",70675364.68
L02A,"ZZZ",19747732853.37

file2.txt
L01B,"AAA",832048921.62
L01E,"DDD",70675364.68
L02A,"ZZZ",19747732853.37
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict ;
  use Date::Simple qw(d8);

  my $firstdate = $ARGV[0];
  my $d1 = d8($firstdate);
 my $seconddate = $ARGV[1];
  my $d2 = d8($seconddate);
  my $f1=$d1-> format ('%d_%m_%Y');
  my $f2=$d2-> format ('%d_%m_%Y');
  print  " $f1 \t";
  print "$f2\n";
  open(my $fh1, '<', $f1) or die "Could not open file '$f1' $!";
  open(my $fh2, '<', $f2) or die "Could not open file '$f2' $!";

  while ( my $line1 = <$fh1>) {
           chomp $line1;
           if ($line1 =~/L01B/){
               my @array = split /[,]+/,$line1;
               {
               while (my $line2 = <$fh2>)
               {
               if ($line2 =~/L01B/){

               my @array1  = split /[,]+/,$line2;
               print " match found sec $array1[0]\n";
              print " match found sec $array1[1]\n";
              print " match found sec $array1[2]\n";
              print " match found first $array[0]\n";
              print " match found first $array[1]\n";
              print " match found first $array[2]\n";
              }

              }
              }
             }
             if ($line1 =~/L01B/){
               my @array2 = split /[,]+/,$line1;
               {
               while (my $line2 = <$fh2>)
               {
               if ($line2 =~/L01A/){

               my @array3  = split /[,]+/,$line2;
               print " match found sec $array2[0]\n";
              print " match found sec $array2[1]\n";
              print " match found sec $array2[2]\n";
              print " match found first $array3[0]\n";
              print " match found first $array3[1]\n";
              print " match found first $array3[2]\n";
              }

              }
              }

             }

             }
    close($fh1);
    close($fh2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For quick Fix, load the file contents to an array as follows

```
open(fh1, '<', $f1) or die "Could not open file '$f1' $!";
my @file1= <fh1>;
close(fh1);

open(fh2, '<', $f2) or die "Could not open file '$f2' $!";
my @file2= <fh2>;
close(fh2);
```

Now instead of while loop try and see using the foreach loop as shown below

`foreach my $line1 (@file1)`

@volverin : I have not tested the codes , just made some changes for you to refer .

praveenzx~

Answer (score 1):

In the inner loop, you exhaust `$fh2`. In the next iteration of the outer loop, `<$fh2>` returns `undef`, as the filehandle has already read the whole file.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but if the files are synchronised (i.e. n<sup>th</sup> line of file1 always corresponds to n<sup>th</sup> line in file2), you can just read one file from each handle; otherwise, the common practice is to hash one file and then process the second one line by line, checking the interesting values in the hash.

Comment: @chorobo the lines are not corresponding ..i am matching one string in two files and spliting both lines of two different files.as i need to do operation on values and then need to print..

Comment: @Volverine: So use hashes. There are plenty of similar questions here or on [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org).